# Is independence of subproblems in dynamic programming an issue?

Tags: algorithm, dynamic-programming

While reading CLRS section 15.3 about "When I should use dynamic programming." and during the explanation of Optimal substructure they gave 2 examples, they are unweighted longest simple path and unweighted shortest path.

They said,

> The subproblems in finding the longest simple path are not independent, whereas for shortest paths they

That's why we can't solve unweighted longest simple path using dynamic programming and I don't have any problem with that but they also said

> Both problems examined in Sections 15.1 and 15.2 have independent subproblems ...... In rod cutting, to determine the best way to cut up a rod of length n, we look at the best ways of cutting up rods of length I for I = 0, 1,..., n-1. Because an optimal solution to the length -n problem includes just one of these subproblem solutions (after we have cut off the first piece), independence of subproblems is not an issue.

The last sentence

> independence of subproblems is not an issue.

Is the independence of subproblems an issue or not? and If not an issue so why they said the first quote or I'm just me misunderstanding something.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem is that you cannot simply merge the answers to two dependent subproblems.

If problems are independent, that is fine.  If you only look at one subproblem, likewise that is fine.  But if you need to combine 2 answers and they are dependent, you have to maintain some additional state.

Where, as in the case of the longest simple path, "some additional state" may blow up on you exponentially. :-)

Comment: You said that if I need to combine 2 answers and they are dependent, I have to maintain some additional state, but that doesn’t mean I can’t solve them by DP or it’ll have no affect if I use DP in runtime. What I want to say is that if subproblems are dependent it’s waste of time to solve it using DP or it can give me better runtime.

Comment: @ModyElSayed It depends on the nature of the dependency.  If the additional state doesn't blow up, then you can.